# Should PostgreSQL be Installed on a Server Machine for Multi-User Access?

Tags: postgresql

I am hoping to set up a database using PostgreSQL which multiple internal users should be able to access.
I am relatively new to administrating databases so I am unsure where the best place is for me to install the software.
Would it be best for me to check with my IT department to see if we have a server machine that I could install the database on?

Comment: Yes, a database server should be installed on a server machine. What would be the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It can be installed to a server or you can buy it as a cloud service.

As your organization has an IT department, you should ask their opinion first.

Comment: Or you can install it on servers in a cloud service.

Comment: That could be seen as installing it on server. One advantage of using a subscribed service is that they usually take care or backups, version upgrades and other operational details. If your time is more valuable than what it costs, do consider paying someone else to do it.